# FullCalendar edit resource on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

So I'm using the Scheduler plugins from FullCalendar library version 3. I already have my event system working, letting me edit events on click via a modal box.

Now I would like to do the same with resources but I'm hitting a wall there.

Among other things, I tried this

```
resourceRender: function(resource, cellEls) {
    cellEls.on('click', function(resource) {
        $.getScript(resource.edit_url);
    })
}
```

But I can't access resource inside cellEls method.

I did not find any example of this so I'm not even sure it's possible.

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to any "click" callback is the JavaScript event object. You can't change that.

Simply allow the "resource" object to propagate down into the event handler naturally instead of trying to re-declare it:

```
resourceRender: function(resource, labelTds, bodyTds) {
    labelTds.on('click', function(event) {
        console.log(resource);
        $.getScript(resource.edit_url);
    });
}
```

Comment: Works fine thanks. However I may have another question. If I comment `respond_to do |format| ... end` in my controller I get this error `ResourcesController#update is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: []`. Not sure how I get rid of that.

Comment: if it works fine, please mark the answer as accepted and/or upvote it - thanks :-). If you have another separate question, please ask a new question. I cannot answer that here, it seems to be unrelated to your original issue, and there's not enough information just in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

This post is already outdated. This has since changed in version Full Calendar Resource Timeline Schedular version 4.0. I used an 'addEventListener' to the DOM object 'el' See the below snippet calling 'resourceRender' so you can see how to access this for a click event on the resource cell after render completes.

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
   var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        schedulerLicenseKey: '<hidden>',
        plugins: ['interaction', 'resourceTimeline'],
        resourceLabelText: 'Resources',
        resources: "<see fullcalendar support docs>",
        events: "<see fullcalendar support docs>",
        resourceRender: function (renderInfo) {
           renderInfo.el.addEventListener("click", function(){ console.log('clicked:' + renderInfo.resource.id); });
        }
    });
         calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: It's not outdated if you're still a user of version 3. 3 and 4 are so different code wise, but so many people are still using and working with V3 that IMO it's simply better to tag the question (as I have just done) with the relevant version, than to consider the question or answers to be "outdated"... instead they're simply "different"